# jasmine-node - including helper

Tags: node.js, meteor, jasmine, jasmine-node

I am trying to test my [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) application with [jasmine-node](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node).  I've stubbed out some methods of Meteor framework in the helper (**spec_helper.js**):

```
  var Meteor = {
    startup: function (newStartupFunction) {
        Meteor.startup = newStartupFunction;
    },
    Collection: function (collectionName) {
        Meteor.instantiationCounts[collectionName] = Meteor.instantiationCounts[collectionName] ?
            Meteor.instantiationCounts[collectionName] + 1 : 1;
    },
    instantiationCounts: {}
  };
```

At this point I need to run the code in **spec_helper.js** (something equivalent of including a module in other languages).  I've tried the following, but no success:

```
require(['spec_helper'], function (helper) {
    console.log(helper); // undefined
    describe('Testing', function () {
        it('should test Meteor', function () {
            // that's what I want to call from my stubs... 
            // ...it's obviously undefined
            Meteor.startup();
        });
    });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Btw, this could also point to an issue with your require configuration. Am assuming you're using the --requireJsSetup and --runWithRequireJs switches. May want to double check that all is properly configured.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`jasmine_node` will autoload helpers (any file containing the word [`helpers`](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node/blob/abfe06a684c00091b24b4918192920c5534b95c2/lib/jasmine-node/cli.js#L218)) from within your spec directory.

**NOTE:** you can cheat and use `helper` instead since it's a substring of `helpers`...makes more sense if you split helpers out across multiple files...singular vs plural.

If you're executing your specs from `specs/unit`, then create a file named `specs/unit/meteor-helper.js`, and `jasmine_node` will automagically source it for you. It will load files with the extension [`.js`](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node/blob/abfe06a684c00091b24b4918192920c5534b95c2/lib/jasmine-node/cli.js#L29) if your specs are written in vanilla JavaScript. If you pass the [`--coffee` switch](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node/blob/abfe06a684c00091b24b4918192920c5534b95c2/lib/jasmine-node/cli.js#L66) on the command line or via your grunt task config (you may even be using gulp if you're ambitious), then it will load helpers with the extensions [`js|coffee|litcoffee`](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node/blob/abfe06a684c00091b24b4918192920c5534b95c2/lib/jasmine-node/cli.js#L72).

You should export a `hash` from each helper file as follows:

`specs/unit/meteor-helper.js`

`// file name must contain the word helper
// x-helper is the convention I roll with
module.exports = {
  key: 'value',
  Meteor: {}
}`

Then, `jasmine_node` will [write each key](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node/blob/abfe06a684c00091b24b4918192920c5534b95c2/lib/jasmine-node/index.js#L66) to the [global namespace](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global).

This will allow you to simply type `key` or `Meteor` from your specs, or any system under test (typically code inside your `lib` folder that the specs are executing assertions against).

Additionally, `jasmine_node` will also allow you to suppress the loading of helpers via the `--nohelpers` switch (see [code](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node/blob/abfe06a684c00091b24b4918192920c5534b95c2/lib/jasmine-node/cli.js#L215) or [README](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node) for more details).

This is the proper way to handle helpers for jasmine via node. You may come across some answers/examples that reference a `jasmine.yml` file; or maybe even `spec_helper.js`. But keep in mind that [this is for ruby land](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine-gem) and not node.

**UPDATE:** It appears `jasmine-node` will only source your file if it contains the word `helpers`. Naming each helper file `x-helper.js|coffee|litcofee` should do the trick. i.e. `meteor-helper.coffee`.

Comment: And remember to set the --test-dir to the folder that the helper is in.